# Symfony2 Bundle configuration based on database entries

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, dependency-injection

I'm using JMSI18nRoutingBundle. I need to create function, which will allow administrator to create new languages from CMS
The problem is, how can I get available languages from database(stored in "locale" table), and use them in JMS bundle configuration. 
E.g.: I have three locales in DB(EN, FR, PL), and i should get result similar to this(but fetched from DB):

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [en, fr, pl] <--
    strategy: prefix
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: To add dynamicaly configuration there is prepend method in BundleExtension. However I am not sure you will be able to $container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'); http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no option to inject any service in configuration file. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It seems, that Symfony doesn't provide any tool to create bundle configuration based on database entries. 
We created a little "work-around" - we have created an .yml file that contains just one parameter(which we are using to configure available languages) and when entries in Locale table are changed, we just rewrite this file with new parameter value.
Simple.